# What are the rarities of each item dropping?

Tags: wizards-unite

In Wizards Unite, I want to know what the drop chances are, so I can know which items to delete and which ones to keep. Does anyone know the drop chances or has tested it?

Comment: Do you mean ingredients mostly?  Not everything you get from Traces can be trashed.  It also depends on what you prefer to use (for instance, if you prefer not to brew certain potions, then you can trash the ingredients used for such potions).

Comment: yes, only ingredients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop rates seem to vary with location and time of day. So using drop rates to decide what to keep seems not the best choice. You'd still probably already know which drops to expect in your 'home' location and don't need to keep those in high quantities.

Instead, look at the potions you want to use and therefore brew. If you have already outgrown the basic potions and only use the 'strong' or 'potent' ones anyway, there is no need in storing ingredients exclusive to those basic potions (e.g. Granian Hair).

Also, if you are like me who mostly plays alone and doesn't do many challenges, you can also drop ingredients that only are useful in fortresses, like adding focus points.